# Getting a Catalog Error when trying to export a COM+ library

Tags: com+, component-services

We've got an old VB6 COM+ component that's running on a 64-bit, Windows 2003 R2 Server with SP2. I need to install the proxy on a new PC and found that the .MSI wasn't there, so I thought I'd get into Component Services and export it. I tried, but got the following error message:

"Catalog Error
An error occurred while processing the last operation.
Error code 8002801D - Library not registered.

The event log may contain additional troubleshooting information."

Well, the event log didn't contain any additional information. Anyway, I'm confused by this error because several applications around site are running using this COM+ service on that server, so I don't know why it would say that the library isn't registered. But more to the point, I see the package in Component Services on the server and it's running. Why can't I export a proxy to be used on the new PC?

Comment: Have you tried delving deeper with Process Monitor or API Monitor?

Comment: No, I haven't. I didn't even think of that. I'll try to give that a try next week when I'm back at work. Thank you!